# How to run a node.js without using a server

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm doing research trying to figure out why a certain virtual environment is run using a node.js server. I haven't really used node.js before and am quite unfamiliar with javascript to begin with. But my goal is to take this node.js and see if I can use the javascript code without having to initiate a server. From what I can tell, the virtual environment only uses the node.js server to display "non-essential" icons. How would I go about running the javascript files themselves, because all we need is the computational power of the code.

Comment: Not certain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You only need to initiate a server if you need to, you know... serve things.

Comment: Can i just take the javascript code from the node.js and run it like any other javascript program?

Answer (score 6):

Initiating a server is just part of what NodeJS does.

Assuming that you just want to do something functional or scripts, just write a `.js` file as it is, using NodeJS's libraries, then run it by executing `node` binary on the file.

For example:

```
var foo = 'apple';
console.log(foo);
```

Save the contents into `myTestFile.js`, and run `node myTestFile.js` in your cmd/terminal/console, and you will see it output a console log of the string 'apple'.